# Why does the index.html file not reference sencha-touch-all.js when I run the package command?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I created a simple `Hello World` application using Sencha Architect. The program automatically creates an `app.html` file, not `index.html`. Everything works great in my browser.

Next, I run the package command from Sencha Architect and it creates 100's of files in my project folder, including `index.html`, `app.json`, `packager.json`, etc.

The main difference between the `app.html` and the `index.html` file is the following line:

```
<_script src="http://cdn.sencha.com/touch/sencha-touch-2.2.1/sencha-touch-all.js"></script>"
```

** I added an underscore because this line was editted out

Without this line, the index.html doesn't work in the browser but the `app.html` does.

I could add this line manually to the `index.html` file but it gets overwritten every time I run the packager program.

Does anybody know why this is occurring? Is there an option or something I'm missing?

Comment: <script src="http://cdn.sencha.com/touch/sencha-touch-2.2.1/sencha-touch-all.js"></script>

Comment: take a deeper look... are you sure there's no difference other than this line?